# Updated Nvidia drivers, Ubuntu OS won't start, can access BIOS and safe-mode

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, gpu

I got a new Nvidia GPU and I read that I had to purge all of the current drivers to avoid collisions. I removed everything, replaced the GPU with the new one, turned the PC on. It worked, I was able to load the OS, but the GPU wasn't recognized using `nvidia-smi`. When used `lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}` I was able to see that the system detects that there is some gpu, without the name of the model.

I downloaded a new driver from Nvidia
[image]

Then I got the file, I tried to open it. It took an hour to open, and then suddenly closed.

Then I restarted my PC, in case it might help. Since then, I couldn't get to access Ubuntu. Every time I am trying to turn the PC on, it looks like the system starts, there is a "TUF gaming into logo" which always comes before Ubuntu turned on. Now, suddenly it changes into this screen

[image]
and just becomes like an empty and unresponsive terminal page.

- I can access bios and safe start by pressing on `F2`
- I can go into safe mode via pressing `ctrl+alt+F3` AFTER the 2nd screenshot above. There, I can travel through dictionaries in my computer. Problem is, that for some reason my WiFi dongle doesn't work, so every time I try to install something (say by using `sudo-apt get install nvidia-driver-535` I get an error that basically says Temporary failure resolving `us.storage.ubuntu.com`

How can I resolve this issue? There is some problem with the graphic card's drivers, but I don't have any access to the Internet to fix things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu already has Nvidia drivers properly packaged in its official repository. There's NEVER a need to install them using the Nvidia's binaries. As a matter of fact that's strongly discouraged.**

And whenever the new card is supported by the same driver version branch already installed there's no need to uninstall anything. If desired you can later try a newer version, if available, simply by using the Additional Drivers tool that effectively purges the installed version and install the newly selected one in its place. Reboot required.

Now, according to your report, you can't use the WiFi in the TTY (NOT "Safe Mode", nothing to do with it, it's simply a command line only console)... Although you can make it work after logging in there's really no point in teaching you all the steps for something so simple as this so just use USB tethering (all it takes is a few MBs of data and a couple of minutes of your time).

Do:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

followed by

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

No need to specify any version, the tool will select the recommended one for you. Reboot.

In most cases you won't even need to do the second step in CLI because after purging the proprietary drivers it should fallback to the default `nouveau` driver and this should give you a graphical interface unless the new card is so new to not have some support with the community driver yet. Of course, the first step doesn't require internet, at all. It goes without saying that you should try that and then, if all goes well (meaning: booting to a graphical desktop, WiFi and everything else) you can and should use the aforementioned Additional Drivers tool, select and apply the required Nvidia proprietary drivers version. Reboot. Done!

Comment: Thanks so much, I guess that it would have helped, but unfortunately the binary file screwed my system so much that I had to reboot. Thanks though!